# Does the yellow stick smash have less impact than a normal joystick smash in Melee?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

I am a casual player, and with all my mates with whom I play Smash Melee, we agreed to ban the `C` yellow joystick smash technique because it was making the smash way faster and we decided to ban this way of winning.

Now that I grew older, I'm still wondering if the yellow joystick on the GameCube controller was only faster but not hitting as strong has left joystick + `A` would hit.

Is there any difference between the two hits (damage and impact of how much the opponent will get thrown away)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [super smash bros wiki](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/C-Stick), the C-Stick is just a shortcut and changes nothing to the damage done or the attack's range :

> **C-Stick**
>
> [...]
>
> In Brawl, the C-Stick (And right stick on the classic controller) can be assigned other control behaviors:
>
> Smash: (Default) Smash attack short cuts, just like in Melee

In other words, when you're "C-sticking", **the smash damage is exactly the same** as the using the combination of `left stick + A`, though the C-stick can be executed much quicker.

[Additional interesting information](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Is_c-sticking_considered_cheating%3F) can be found about the advantages and disadvantages of both methods:

> The C stick is one frame slower than using A and cannot be charged.
>   The A, on the other hand, can do more knockback (with the charge) and
>   is easier to repeatedly tap. In short, the C stick is just like using
>   X to jump or Y to grab. It's a different mechanism for control that
>   can be used without any form of bad sportsmanship.

Comment: I don't see how using a button on your controller could be considered cheating.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that smash attacks can be charged. Thus a fast smash is also a weak smash.

A smash attack using the A button will almost always be more powerful than a C-stick smash; because the human reactions are slower the smash will be charged for at least some frames, while the C-stick smash has no charge at all.

This changes in SSB4, where the C-stick smash can be charged, but also becomes slower (in my hands anyway) than an A-button smash.